# How to add a value in one column to the end of another value in a different column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, emoji

I have some data, and I am trying to add the emojis from one column to the end of each sentence in a different column - if this is possible?

For example, this is a sample of what my data looks like:

| Sentence | Emoji |
| --- | --- |
| I love you | ❤️ |
| I am so cool |  |
| Too hot today | ☀️ |

Now, using Python - or maybe something similar - is it possible to add each emoji from the `Emoji` column to the end of each corresponding sentence in the `Sentence` column?

For example, something like this:

| Sentences |
| --- |
| I love you ❤️ |
| I am so cool |
| Too hot today ☀️ |

So far, I have looked around the community and found no solutions (or anything similar) to what I am trying to achieve.

I am unsure how to do this, but I do require some assistance.

Thanks.

Comment: `df['sentences'] = df.agg(' '.join,1)` works for me? also there is `.str.cat` and plain old dirty concatenation `df['Sentence'] + ' ' + df['Emoji']`

Comment: Hi, @Umar.H - thanks for the reply and solution. It has successfully worked for me, so a big, big thank you. Have a nice day; you have helped me so much.